Независимость Δt движков от FPS
Описание
Сделал две движки разных скоростей и точности. Вот основная их рабочая часть:
1.
let previous = 0;
const callback = (current) => {
    const difference = current - previous;
    if (this.launched) {
        this.#FPS = (1000 / difference);
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event(`update`));
    }
    previous = current;
    requestAnimationFrame(callback);
};
requestAnimationFrame(callback);




let previous = performance.now();
const callback = (current) => {
    const difference = current - previous;
    if (this.launched) {
        this.#FPS = (1000 / difference);
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event(`update`));
    }
    previous = current;
    setTimeout(callback, this.#gap, performance.now());
};
setTimeout(callback, this.#gap, performance.now());

Они отлично работают, но основная проблема у обоих то, что Δt (разница времени между кадров) рассчитывается от FPS (количество кадров в секунду). А если программа лагает, то и FPS падает, соответственно и Δt прыгает вверх.
И вся физика, которая считается от Δt, начинает демонстрировать невероятное шоу.
Вопрос
Возможно ли создать движок, рассчитывающий разницу времени статически, даже при лагах?
Если да, то как?

Фишка в том, что Δt при обновлении игрового состояния должен быть константой. При этом интервал времени следует рассчитывать от начала работы, а обновление производить за каждое увеличение этого интервала на Δt (т.е. если с момента предыдущего вызова прошло много времени, то состояние надо будет обновить несколько раз за один вызов).

@user7860670 как понять это "много времени"?

Например, если Δt 16мс, предыдущий вызов был в 2000мс от начала, а этот в 2040мс от начала.

@user7860670 на словах понятно. Но как мне заставить кодом понять, что 40мс для этого процессора много где обычно 16мс и нужно повторить ещё сколько-то раз чтобы компенсировать потерю.

Как-то неудобно тыкать в арифметику, за 3 класс... 2000 / 16 = 125; 2040 / 16 = 127 стало быть обновить надо еще 2 раза. Одно должно было быть в 2016 и еще одно в 2032.

Недопонляи. В начале иногда движок запускается медленно иногда быстро. То есть в начале может быть как 16мс так и 200мс и это на конкретном компьютере. На другом это может быть как 30мс так и 50мс так и 600мс. Как программа должна понять из всех этих разных цифр что именно 16 нормальная задержка для этого ПК и 50 для другого?

Интервал задается константой в коде и не зависит от ПК. Он никак не зависит от того, насколько медленно или быстро запускается движок.

@user7860670 вот сейчас понял)

Физика, которая меняет поведение при изменении dt - это баг. Исправьте физику и работайте с переменным dt.

@StanislavVolodarskiy ну а как же ещё мне считать, например ускорение если не (v - v₀) / ⍙t?

@eccs0103, ускорение определяется не тем какое dt, а тем какие силы действуют на какие массы. Если для разных dt получаются разные ускорения, значит ошибка в вычислении v, изменение которого зависит от dt.

Ещё раз, если физическая симуляция зависит от dt, ошибка в физической симуляции.

@StanislavVolodarskiy ну хорошо. У меня есть силы, я считаю общею силу, потом я получаю a = F / m ускорение и хочу получить изменение скорости ⍙v = a ⍙t. Если ⍙t выдает разные значения я получаю разную скорость.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Что-то вы напутали. Просто передвижение с плавающей dt быстро приведет к расхождениям, а уж с эмуляцией физики будет полный караул. Многие физические движки предполагают вычисления с фиксированным шагом эмуляции.

@eccs0103, через одну секунду у вас скорость одна, через две секунды в два раза больше. Главная идея: если вы сделаете два шага по одной секунде или если вы сделаете один шаг в две секунды, вы получите в итоге одну и ту же скорость.

@StanislavVolodarskiy " если вы сделаете два шага по одной секунде или если вы сделаете один шаг - две секунды, вы получите в итоге одну и ту же скорость" - Это только в математике так работает. А эмуляция, использующая целые числи или числа с плавающей точкой так вести  себя не будет.

@user7860670, не понял ваше возражение. Я говорю, что аккуратная физическая симуляция не требует фиксировать шаг. А что говорите вы?

@StanislavVolodarskiy Я говорю, что аккуратная физическая симуляция требует фиксированный шаг. И не только я, но и авторы популярных физических движков типа box2d или Bullet. Причем не просто фиксированный, а из достаточно узкого диапазона. Написать движок, одинакого хорошо эмулирующий миллисекунды и столетия - задача нетривиальная. А "аккуратная физическая симуляция не требует фиксировать шаг" - это что-то из области фантастики.

Никому не нужны столетия. Нужны миллисекунды: от 5 до 40. В этих диапазонах сделать сделать симуляцию можно. Для больших диапазонов можно подразбивать. Для меньших интерполировать.

@StanislavVolodarskiy допустим у объекта стабильное ускорение 1м/с² и я хочу считать ⍙v. Если ⍙t не стабильна, то при лагах я получаю более высокие значения. То есть при реальном времени 1 секунда я могу получить ⍙t 2 секунды. При этом ускорение тот же. Соответственно у меня аж 2 раза высокая скорость чем должно быть.

@eccs0103, dv не имеет смысла без dt. Смысл есть только в dv/dt - ускорении. А оно при любом шаге должно быть одинаковым. В два раза более высокая скорость будет через в два раза большее время.

@StanislavVolodarskiy для компьютера - да, именно так. Компьютер считает, что прошло 2 секунды и увеличивает v тоже чтобы v / t был одинаковым. Но для наблюдающего прошло не 2 секунды, а 1 секунда остановка кадра и 1 нормальная секунда. Наблюдающий видит за 1 секунду то, что компьютер расчитал для 2 секунд. Вот об этом я говорю.

рассчитывается от FPS ... если программа лагает, то и FPS падает мб просто не тот фпс берёте? кмк нужен не тот который выплёвывается из движка, а тот который принимается монитором(герцовка, частота обновления - это тоже иногда фпс"ом называют. 60грц монитор = монитор с 60фпс). всё таки мы не в сферический вакуум кадры отправляем.

@eccs0103, и компьютер и пользователь используют одни и те же часы. Если это не так, сделайте чтобы это было так.

@puffleeck да там всего то 1 фпс) в вопросе показано как оно считается

@StanislavVolodarskiy Если это не так, сделайте чтобы это было так. — вот это уже не ко мне. Это уже к создателям DOM. Какие часы мне дали такие я и использую)

@eccs0103, баг вот тут: "И вся физика, которая считается от Δt, начинает демонстрировать невероятное шоу."

@user7860670 кстати, ваш метод я сейчас проверил и пока без проблем работает. Можете оформить как ответ
